# Raspberry Pi3 need to install media

Tags: sd-card

How do I remove partition from the sd card that came with the system, as you said in the incomplete instructions, it reads like a 1 Gb card and its' marked 32 gb.  I can't load any other files (media) to the card.  I have tried copy and paste on another disc and it won't start Pi up.   Help.  This should be simple, but it's got me.

Comment: Did you expand the filesystem? What is the output of df -h? As who said?

Comment: I am trying to get help on expanding the file system on the sd card without erasing the files that I know work.  How do you expand it?

Answer (score 2):

From the command line type `sudo raspi-config` one of the first options should be expand filesystem.